# Installing prerequisites after setup ended(inno setup)

Tags: inno-setup, prerequisites

How should i do this?
I found many answers but they're not for inno,and probably are not for my problem.
If someone knows how to do this,post the solution here

Comment: You can use [`[Run]` section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)

Comment: If you are going to install something after app. installation, then it's not a prerequisite. Prerequisites are installed  before app. They are components needed to run your app. and as such should be installed before the app. They may also require system reboot and that's what is the event I mentioned prepared.

Comment: @TLama In that case,how are called this ones after installation?

Comment: I don't think that they are called somehow. Maybe postrequisites :) But my comment to your previous question was targeted to prerequisites, such as DirectX should be installed before your app., not after.

Comment: Yeah,okay,then is there any difference between running directx redist and such after or before install,i mean in code difference?

Comment: Yes, there is. I can post you a sample script (if someone won't be faster) when I get to my desktop. It would take ages to write it on my Z2 device..

Comment: That's ok just don't hurry.Yeah,typing such complex codes on mobile would last really long :)

Comment: There is no need to install DX before installing app files. It is needed to be installed before running the app, so using the `[RUN]` section or `afterinstall` is fair enough. Installing the 3rd app prerequisite before installing the app itself is needed only then if the installer requires this prerequisite to run.

Comment: @RobeN, though you are technically right, what would your app. do if e.g. required version of DirectX setup fails, or requires reboot ? Will you tell the user that they probably (because your app. does not know how the setup finished) need to e.g. reboot their system so the app. starts to work at the app. start ?

Comment: @RobeN I agree with TLamas opinion because it is better for prerequisites to run on end of setup,running prerequisites right on beggining would break install(if of course restart of system is needed)

Comment: That is why I have suggested `[Run]` section which is triggered after installing all files. Just wanted to point out that you can still call it prerequisite (for the app). Sometimes - which is not really good solution - specific installers need prerequisites to run itself. E.g. there were some 3D installers which needed DX to be installed or Java based installers which need Java libraries to be present in system to run. But these are not good solutions and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @RobeN i really am avoiding that kind of installers
i do use run section which you recomended,but prerequisite installes BEFORE finished page,which is a problem for me,because i want to change finished page so that user can check what of prerequisites he wants to install,you understand what i think?

Comment: You can add checkboxes for `RUN` section to allow user selection of specific prequisites to be installed. You can also make it more complex and add `Checks` in `Code` section for each `Run` line that would check if specific prequisite should be installed or not.

Comment: Exactly what i want,how would it look in code?

Comment: Is anyone going to answer on my request?